# Coordinate ring of complete intersection Calabi Yau (CICY)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry

I am quite new in commutative algebra so I would be grateful if you could clarify to me this issue.

I would like to construct the coordinate ring, $A$,  of a Calabi Yau threefold $X$ which is a complete intersection of two hypersurfaces $h_{1}$ and $h_{2}$ in the ambient space $\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{P}^{1}\times\mathbb{P}^{2}\times\mathbb{P}^{2}$.

We can choose projective coordinates: $x=[x_{0}:x_{1}] $ for $\mathbb{P}^{1}$, $y=[y_{0}:y_{1}:y_{2}]$ for the first $\mathbb{P}^{2}$ and $z=[z_{0}:z_{1}:z_{2}]$ for the other $\mathbb{P}^{2}$.
The configuration matrix is: (it is the Schoen manifold)

\begin{equation}
X\left[\begin{array}{c||ccc}
\mathbb{P}^{1}&1& 1\\
\mathbb{P}^{2}&0& 3\\
\mathbb{P}^{2}&3& 0\\
\end{array}\right]=
\begin{cases}
 x_{0}f_{0}(y)-x_{1}f_{1}(y)=0&  \\ 
 x_{0}g_{0}(z)-x_{1}g_{1}(z)=0 &  
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $f_{0}, f_{1}, g_{0}, g_{1}$ are homogeoneous cubic polynomials.

I know that for a single projective factor, for example the quintic in $\mathbb{P}^{4}$ I can use $A=R_{\mathbb{P}^{4}}/I=\mathbb{C}[x_{0},x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}]/\left ( \sum_{i=0}^{4} x_{i}^{5}+\psi x_{0}x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}x_{4} \right )$

---

**EDIT1**
My initial guess was that: 
\begin{gather}
\nonumber
A
=(\mathbb{C}[x_{0},x_{1},y_{0},y_{1},y_{2},z_{0},z_{1},z_{2}]/ \left( x_{0}( \sum_{i=0}^{2} y_{i}^{3}+\psi_{a} y_{0}y_{1}y_{2})-x_{1}( \sum_{i=0}^{2} y_{i}^{3}+\psi_{b} y_{0}y_{1}y_{2}) \\  , x_{0}( \sum_{i=0}^{2} z_{i}^{3}+\psi_{c} z_{0}z_{1}z_{2})-x_{1}( \sum_{i=0}^{2} z_{i}^{3}+\psi_{d} z_{0}z_{1}z_{2}) \right )
\end{gather}

---

**EDIT2**
I think I will follow equation $(3.3)$ of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.2186.pdf)  in which the coordinate ring of a CICY is explained.

Comment: Crossposted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/314833.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't correct. The homogenous coordinate ring doesn't behave this way with respect to taking products, essentially since $\mathbb{P^n}\times \mathbb{P^m}$ is not $\mathbb{P^{n+m}}$. See this answer for some explicit examples of coordinate rings of products, [Homogeneous coordinate rings of product of two projective varieties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630899/homogeneous-coordinate-rings-of-product-of-two-projective-varieties).

What you'd have to do here is embed $\mathcal{A}$ into a projective space $\mathbb{P^N}$ via the Segre embedding, write the equations defining $X$ in the coordinates on $\mathbb{P^N}$,  then the homogenous coordinate ring will be the polynomial ring in $N+1$ variables quotiented by the polynomials defining $\mathcal{A}$, and the (new) polynomials defining $X$.

Comment: Thanks. in fact I had done this in the beginning, but I seemed strange to me because I couldn´t write the equations of $X$ in the coordinates of Segre embedding $[x_{0}y_{o}z_{0},..,x_{1}y_{2}z_{2}]$ at first sight, maybe I was doing something wrong, I will check it again more carefully.