# Image of the Segre embedding of an hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Suppose that my initial envoirenment space is $\mathbb{P}^{4}$ with homogeneous coordinates $[x_{0}:x_{1}:x_{2}:x_{3}:x_{4}]$ and I define an hypersurface with equation (for example) $h:x_{0}x_{3}+2x_{1}x_{2}-3x_{4}^2=0$.

I also define the coordinates $[y_{0}:y_{1}]$ for a second projective space $\mathbb{P}^{1}$.

Now I embedd the product of the two projective varieties using the Segre embedding $\mathbb{P}^{4}\times\mathbb{P}^{1}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^{9}$ with coordintes $[x_{0}y_{0},x_{1}y_{0},x_{2}y_{0},x_{3}y_{0},x_{4}y_{0},x_{0}y_{1},x_{1}y_{1},x_{2}y_{1},x_{3}y_{1},x_{4}y_{1}]$

What I understand is that now my envoirenment space is going to be $\mathbb{P}^{9}$, but what I want to know is the following: ***which are going to be the defining equations of my hypersurface $h$ when it is embedded into $\mathbb{P}^{9}$?***

---

I have no idea about how to proceed, maybe I am misunderstanding something important. My only "reasonable" guess is that now the hypersurface could be:

$h=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{0}y_{0}x_{3}y_{0}+2x_{1}y_{0}x_{2}y_{0}-3(x_{4}y_{0})^2=0\\ 
x_{0}y_{1}x_{3}y_{1}+2x_{1}y_{1}x_{2}y_{1}-3(x_{4}y_{1})^2=0
\end{matrix}\right.$

(At least in this way there is kind of a "match" in the dimensions as $\mathbb{P}^{3}\times\mathbb{P}^{1}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^{7}$ and generally (for a complete intersection) two equations in $\mathbb{P}^{9}$ will define a $7-$manifold)

Comment: There's also the Segre equations, basically the equations that define the image of the Segre map.  Also, is your hypersurface $\{h=0\}\times\mathbb{P}$ or something else?

Comment: $h$ isn't even homogeneous; can you elaborate? There are equations for finding the image of the Segre embedding, I think Milne's notes has a good treatment. I would link them but I'm on mobile.

Comment: Sorry you´re right, I have just re-written $h$ (the thing is that $h$ is not my interest case but this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989121/coordinate-ring-of-complete-intersection-calabi-yau-cicy (that´s the reason why I haven´t check $h$ case more carefully)), I have also taken a look to Milne´s notes and I haven´t seen anything clarifier